# show isomorphism by using characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$K^n$ is considered as a $K[x]$-modul  for a matrix $A\in M_n(K)$. That is $p(x)\circ v=p(A)v$ with $v\in K^n$, $p\in K[x]$. Let now $A\in M_2\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ be a matrix having two different eigenvalues. I have to show the following isomorphism:  $\left.\mathbb{C}\left[x\right]\middle/ p_A\left(t\right)\right.\cong\mathbb{C^2}$ as $\mathbb{C}\left[x\right]$–modules.

$p_A\left(t\right)$ is the characteristic polynomial. Can anyone give me a hint how to deal  with this?

Comment: The question really is only about polynomials, once you've got $p_A$ the exact value of $A$ is not used in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited missing informations

Answer (score 4):

First of all I am assuming the $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module structure on $\mathbb{C}^2$ is given via $x\cdot v=Av$. We want an $\mathbb{C}[x]$-linear map $\phi: \mathbb{C}[x]\to \mathbb{C}^2$. Suppose $u,v$ are eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalues $t_1, t_2$. Let $\phi(1)=w:=u-v$ and define for $f(x)\in \mathbb{C}[x]$
$$
\phi(f(x))=f(A)w
$$
First of all note that if $p_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial, by Cayley-Hamilton $p_A(A)=0$, meaning $p_A(x)\in \ker\phi$. Suppose now $f(x)\in \ker\phi$, then  $f(A)w=0$. Then
$$
0=f(A)w=f(A)(u-v)=f(t_1)u-f(t_2)v\Longrightarrow f(t_1)u=f(t_2)v\Longrightarrow f(t_1)=f(t_2)=0
$$
The last part is because $u,v$ are linearly independent. This means $p_A\mid f$, or $f\in (p_A)$. As a result $\ker \phi=(p_A)$.

Now we show $\phi$ is surjective. Take any vector $au+bv\in \mathbb{C}^2$. Then
$$
\phi
\left[\frac{a(x-t_2)+b(x-t_1)}{t_1-t_2}
\right]=
\frac{a(A-t_2)+b(A-t_1)}{t_1-t_2}w
= au+bv
$$
This shows that $\mathbb{C}^2\simeq \mathbb{C}[x]/(p_A(x))$ as $\mathbb{C}[x]$-modules.

By the way this is by no means a natural ismorphism, as an example $\phi(1)=u+v$ would've worked just as easily. In fact any $\phi(1)=\alpha u+\beta v$ with $\alpha, \beta\neq 0$ works perfectly alright too.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited some missing informations  but I think your answer goes well with the defintion $p(x)\circ v=p(A)v$ , right?

Comment: Yes that's what I used...

Answer (score 1):

Some hinting: write $\;P_A(t)=(t-t_1)(t-t_2)\;$ , so

$$\Bbb C[t]/\langle\; (t-t_1)(t-t_2)\;\rangle\cong_{\Bbb C}\Bbb C[t]/\langle\; (t-t_1)\;\rangle\times\Bbb C[t]/\langle\; (t-t_2)\;\rangle$$

For example, you could try the map

$$\phi:\Bbb C[t]\to\Bbb C[t]/\langle\; (t-t_1)\;\rangle\times\Bbb C[t]/\langle\; (t-t_2)\;\rangle\;,\;\;\text{defined by:}$$

$$\phi(g(t):=\left(\;g(t)+\langle\; (t-t_1)\;\rangle,\,g(t)+\langle\; (t-t_2)\;\rangle\;\right)$$

Show the above is a surjection (you may want to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem) and then use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: This shows that $\mathbb{C}[X]/p_{A}(X)$ and $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ are isomorphic as rings, but not necessarily as $\mathbb{C}[X]$-modules, so one needs to also verify that the usual map arising from the Chinese Remainder Theorem is actually a $\mathbb{C}[X]$-module homomorphism. For instance, the $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ modules $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x, y)$ and $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x-1, y-1)$ are isomorphic as rings, but not as $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ modules, since they have different annihilators.

Comment: I guess one needs to say what the $\mathbb C[x]$-structure on $\mathbb C^2$ is. Probably it's the one coming from $A$. Then you might need to jiggle things around to get the eigenspaces to match up. I don't think it's canonical.

Comment: Right, I imagine it's $p(X) \cdot (v, w) = p(A)(v, w)$ for $p \in \mathbb{C}[X], (v, w) \in \mathbb{C}^{2}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited some missing informations